# Group authorization using Azure AD ADAL.JS - NodeJS, ReactJS

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, adal

I've seen that when using ADAL.js, you cannot get group membership claims due to some URL limitation.

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/239

I am using oauth-bearer authentication from the frontend, that is, the frontend triggers a login via the AD login page.
The client then pass the access token to the backend.

What I want to do:

I want to filter some data in my backend endpoints depending on group membership.
e.g. if you are a member of group "London" in AD, you should only see things related to London in our DB queries.

Super simple using e.g. Okta or Auth0, not so much with Azure AD.

I also want to accomplish the same thing on the frontend, that is, show and hide menu items depending on group membership.
(All access is still checked on backend also)

The documentation is sparse and not very helpful.
"You should use Graph API".

How?, how do I talk to graph api using the token I get from the frontend?

This is the setup I have for my Node+Express endpoints:

```
app.use(
  "/contacts",
  passport.authenticate("oauth-bearer", { session: true }),
  contacts
);
```

How, where and when should I call the graph API here?

Our system is super small so I don't mind using session state.
Can I fetch this information when the user logs in?
How should that flow be? client logs in, once logged in, call the backend and request the groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get the access token from Azure AD after the user logged in, you can find the group membership of the user by doing a GET request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf` with the access token like this:

```
function getGroupsOfUser(accessToken, callback) {
  request
   .get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf')
   .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken)
   .end((err, res) => {
     callback(err, res);
   });
}
```

This sample assumes you are using the NPM package [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent).

And the required permissions to call this API are listed [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_memberof#permissions).